# Write in seperable form

Tags: entanglement, textbook-and-exercises

Consider the two-qubit state $$ =
1/4
\{(|00⟩ + |11⟩) (⟨00| + ⟨11|) + (|01⟩ + |10⟩) (⟨01| +
⟨10|)\}.$$ Though looks like an entangled state, it is in fact a separable one. Write it down in the
separable form, i.e., in the form $$ = 1/4 ∑ _
|_
⟩⟨_
|,$$
where all $|_
⟩$ are separable.

Comment: Welcome to QCSE. This looks like an exercise; would you mind sharing what are your ideas, what have you tried so far, or maybe some specific difficulties?

Answer (score 2):

I won't answer your question, but let me give a couple of suggestions for approaches:

- What are the eigenvectors of $\rho$? Is there any freedom in how you select them (i.e. degeneracy) that might let you create separable eigenvectors?
- Can you express the matrix $\rho$ in terms of a tensor product of Pauli operators? Can that suggest a separable basis?

Comment: (+1) I honestly like this approach of giving 'hints' and 'suggestions' when a question is set in this form.